# Можете указать разницу между DetailView и простой функцией?

Tags: django

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Пытаюсь рендерить шаблон с помощью класса и функции. В одном случае все нормально, в другом возникает ошибка. Приведу пример кода и трассировки ошибки.

views.py

```
class ProductView(DetailView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'product.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['cart_product_form'] = CartAddProductForm()
        context['review_form'] = ReviewForm()
        return context

def product_detail(request, pk):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=pk)
    reviews = Review.objects.filter(active=True)
    products = Product.objects.all()
    cart_product_form = CartAddProductForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        review_form = ReviewForm(data=request.POST)
        if review_form.is_valid():
            new_review = review_form.save(commit=False)
            new_review.user = request.user
            new_review.product = product
            new_review.save()
    else:
        review_form = ReviewForm()
    return render(request,
                  'product.html',
                 {'reviews': reviews,
                  'products': products,
                  'review_form': review_form,
                  'cart_product_form': cart_product_form})
```

трассировка:

```
Internal Server Error: /product/2/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Обучение\Django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "d:\Обучение\Django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "d:\Обучение\Django\kosmetica\shop\views.py", line 77, in product_detail
    return render(request,
  File "d:\Обучение\Django\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "d:\Обучение\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "d:\Обучение\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "d:\Обучение\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "d:\Обучение\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "d:\Обучение\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "d:\Обучение\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "d:\Обучение\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "d:\Обучение\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "d:\Обучение\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "d:\Обучение\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "d:\Обучение\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "d:\Обучение\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "d:\Обучение\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "d:\Обучение\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 446, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "d:\Обучение\Django\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "d:\Обучение\Django\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'cart_add' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart/add/(?P<product_id>\\d+)/$']
```

Comment: где у вас `cart_add` и как вы к нему обращаетесь из шаблона?

Answer (score 0):

Все, разобрался. Нужно было передать в шаблон product:

```
return render(request,
                  'product.html',
                 {'reviews': reviews,
                  'products': products,
                  'product': product,
                  'review_form': review_form,
                  'cart_product_form': cart_product_form})
```